# Ruby on Rails Direct AWS S3 Upload with JqueryFileUpload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I want to build a simple File Upload system for my website (only I will be accessing and uploading) to upload my Portfolio Page. My website is on Ruby on Rails, hosted on Heroku.

So I was following the [Heroku Tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#debugging) to upload Images to S3. It uses the `aws-sdk` gem After following through the tutorial, when I try to upload a simple .png file, I received the following error.

```
Bad Request 400: Bucket POST must contain a field named 'key'.  If it is specified, please check the order of the fields.
```

**PortfolioController**

```
 def new
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public_read)
    @portfolio = Portfolio.new()
  end
```

Checking the javascript `formData` value in the View:

```
...
fileInput.fileupload({
                formData:       '<%=@s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>',
                fileInput:      fileInput,
                url:            '<%=@s3_direct_post.url%>',
                type:           'POST',
                autoUpload:     true,
                paramName:      'file',
                dataType:       'XML',
                replaceFileInput: false,

...
```

gives:

```
{
"AWSAccessKeyId"=>"my-access-key",
"key"=>"${filename}",
"policy"=> "long-string",
"signature"=>"randomg-signature-string", 
"success_action_status"=>"201",
"acl"=>"public-read"
}
```

I've tried adding to sync my timing as shown in `/config/initializers/aws.rb`:

```
AWS.config(access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
           secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

AWS::S3.const_set('DEFAULT_HOST', "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com")

S3_BUCKET = AWS::S3.new.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET']]
```

After looking through Google and Stackoverflow, it seems that Jquery might be rebuilding the form data, hence messing up the order of the POST values.

Problem is, I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails and Javascript, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same issue, I decided to surround the image upload with a form and include all the necessary parameters (key, policy, acl etc) as hidden input elements. Then remove the formData: '<...>' line from the js file, and the plugin will use the form data in the order on the page. I ran into one issue with the signature being blank on the form, but since I was able to get the @s3_direct_post.fields onto the page I filled the input with the signature from there before submitting the image upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to follow the [Paperclip Heroku Tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) instead, and was successfully able to upload to S3.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing recently with the same issue and this is the solution :

You have only to change this

```
formData:  '<%=@s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>'
```

To this :

```
formData:  <%=@s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Because `@s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe` will give you something like this :

```
{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}
```

and by wrapping that between `' '` it will make it like this :

```
'{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}'
```

Which is not a valid JSON

**Another solution (but not efficient because the first is more elegant I think)**

By looking at jquery file upload [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data) it says :

> By default, the plugin calls jQuery's serializeArray method on the
>   upload form to gather additional form data for all input fields
>   (including hidden fields)

So you can add those fields to the form (*before the file input*) like this :

```
<% @s3_direct_post.fields.map do |name, value| %>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%= name %>" value="<%= value %>" />
<% end %>

<%= f.file_field :avatar_url%>
...
...
```

**But BE AWARE** because as the documentation tell you it will gather all fields including hidden fields (in you Rails app there are some additional hidden fields like utf8 and authenticity_token) which will gives you an error because Amazon S3 won't accept that!

This is a little hack I did to solve that :

Make a separate form than your initial form, and **assign an id to it**, in my case the id is **fields-for-s3**

```
<form id="fields-for-s3">
    <% @s3_direct_post.fields.map do |name, value| %>
        <input type="hidden" name="<%= name %>" value="<%= value %>" />
    <% end %>
</form>
<%= form_for @user, ..... %>
    ....
<% end %>
```

Then use jQuery [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method on the form (with the specific ID) to create a formData object manually like this :

```
formData: $('form#fields-for-s3').serializeArray()
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem:
You could also call 
    JSON.parse(formdata);
From your javascript.